# "Front-End" technologies

Tags: discussion, survey-2016

I'm a bit confused about what is considered "Front-End" (please see picture below).  I primarily work with Java, Node.js, PHP and SQL on the "Back-End" so to see these listed on a "Front-End" tab doesn't make much sense to me. I would think "Front-End" Java development for instance would be along the lines of Java Swing desktop app development.

[image: "Front-End"]

Comment: Its basically the full-stack list, not specifically front-end.

Comment: I figured that but it still causes me to wonder..."Is this maybe Front-End Java development" since it's listed on a tab with heading "Front-End"

Comment: That would be at best applet development, and we can nowadays safely pretend that never existed :)

Comment: "applet development"?  How about Swing or JavaFX which are both "Front-End" technologies?

Comment: I would take front-end / back-end references with a grain of salt. As you will likely notice if you haven't already, where that line is cut really varies from person to person.

Comment: @SethMcClaine I don't agree.  It's very clear and easy to me what is "Front-End" verses "Back-End".  I understand JavaScript and Java can be used on both of those ends but certainly "Front-End" JavaScript (i.e. AngularJS or jQuery) or Java (i.e. Swing) has a much different scope and code-base than "Back-End" JavaScript (i.e. Node) or Java (i.e. Spring Data or REST).  Could you relay a library or framework that's not specifically catered to "Front-End" or "Back-End" development? There very well might be one but all the ones I work with are specifically oriented towards "Front" or "Back" end.

Comment: What about js frameworks, do the fall as front end or back end. Depends on the company, how they use them, what else the develop in that company. (The part that you started out with "I don't agree" kind of drive to my point, the line is drawn in different places for different people/companies)

Answer (score 3):

As you note, the technologies listed in the chart aren't necessarily front-end technologies. They are technologies used by the highest-paid respondents who identify as "front-end developers". We probably could have been more clear here.

Comment: *"the technologies listed in the char"* Either you meant `char*` (but then it should be `const char*`) or chart, I'm not sure which

Comment: @cat Good catch. I pushed a fix. Will go live with next build =)